# VPN for gaming over the internet (in LAN)

Tags: vpn

I created a VPN to connect my clients to a server and get them into a "LAN".

Need to do some things that a game need to be hosted/joined in this emulated LAN.
I'm working on Warcraft 3 (DOTA) game and I don't know what settings must be configured.

Clients are connected to each other but when anyone creates a game/session, the others can't see him on the list!
(I'm doing these works with programming a client software)
 any idea friends?
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [Tunngle](http://www.tunngle.net/) or [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/).
Both are made to be used for this.

Comment: [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) also has a VPN component and is free for personal use.

Comment: Shiki , I want create a program myself . and don't use others product. do you mean that products are programmable ? i didn't find any thing about it .

Comment: @Mojtaba - But what do you even want to configure? The LAN server browser will just work. It's not meant to be configured. You plug two computers together, that's a LAN. There are no configurations. Simple as that. || If you want to write a new software, check OpenVPN's source code and give yourself a few years.

Comment: What do you mean ? I really mixed up ! you don't want to say 4 players from 4 different point of world can play with each other a game like warcraft just by connecting to a vpn ? So , why others can't see who created the Host game ? and why some guys told me  i must open some ports and do some works ? Shiki ,i'm searching about 10 days and i heared many , but the problem is which solution i must pick ? thanks for help.

Comment: @Mojtaba: A VPN is a complex thing. It's difficult to set up properly. Tunngle, Hamachi, and TeamViewer are VPNs too. But they are easy to set up and use. || If you want to REALLY set up a VPN, please post a new question. Include what VPN solution (PPTP, L2TP, Linux/Windows, etc) are you using and post your configs, everything.